# How to connect google spreadsheet to android app (if using CalendarView)

Tags: android, google-apps-script, calendar

I'm trying to connect my basic calendar app that I made in android studio to a google spreadsheet. I'm a beginner in android studio, and am currently using calendarview as my calendar for my app. Is it possible to read information from a google spreadsheet from my calendar app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Spreadsheets API here is the documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/